# Close SaveFileDialog/OpenFileDialog programmatically without using pinvoke

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

Due to some requirements, I have to close `SaveFileDialog` programmatically without using PINVOKE.

Is there any way to close `SaveFileDialog` other than using the PINVOKE way?
I had tried to close the owner form of the `SaveFileDialog`, but the `SaveFileDialog` still there.

What I had tried:

1. Close the form which execute the `ShowDialog()` of `SaveFileDialog`.
2. `SaveFileDialog.Dispose()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closing the `owner` window passed to the `ShowDialog(owner);` method should work. For example:

```
private static Form CreateDummyForm(Form owner) {
    Form dummy = new Form();
    IntPtr hwnd = dummy.Handle; // force handle creation
    if (owner != null) {
        dummy.Owner = owner;
        dummy.Location = owner.Location;
        owner.LocationChanged += delegate {
            dummy.Location = owner.Location;
        };
    }
    return dummy;
}

[STAThread]
static void Main() {

    Form form = new Form();
    form.Size = new Size(400,400);
    Button btn = new Button { Text = "btn" };
    btn.Click += delegate {
        SaveFileDialog fsd = new SaveFileDialog();
        int timeoutMillis = 5000;
        Form dummy = CreateDummyForm(form); // Close disposes the dummy form
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMillis)).ContinueWith((t) => { dummy.Close(); dummy.Dispose(); }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        fsd.ShowDialog(dummy);
        fsd.Dispose();
    };

    form.Controls.Add(btn);
    Application.Run(form);
}
```

Comment: I didnt think of trying to dispose the owner form after I call `ShowDialog(owner)`. Thanks! it works!

Comment: Use a `using` block, not `Dispose`

Comment: @Charlieface For this method above yes, but for my code the owner form of the `SaveFileDialog` is not a ad-hoc creation , so i still have to use `Close` and `Dispose`

Answer (score 1):

If you use visual studio designer to add a SaveFileDialog, your Form will have a field with this dialog during the life time of your form.

It is way more efficient and way more easier create the SaveFileDialog only when needed. If you do this in a `using` statement, you won't have to take care of Disposing it, and certainly won't need `PInvoke`

```
private void MenuItem_FileSaveAs_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    using (var dlg = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        dlg.FileName = this.FileName;
        dlg.InitialDirectory = ...
        dlg.DefaultExt = ...
        ...

        // Show the SaveFileDialog, and if Ok save the file
        var dlgResult = dlg.ShowDialog(this);
        if (dlgResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // operator selected a file and pressed OK
            this.FileName = dlg.FileName;
            this.SaveFile(this.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```